# Showing a function is injective in topology

Tags: general-topology, functions

I am taking a topology course, we are working with Munkres. The question I am currently working on is:

Show that $(X_1\times\cdot\cdot\cdot\times X_{n−1})\times X_n$ is homeomorphic with $X_1\times\cdot\cdot\cdot\times X_n$.

Since this is an introductory course, I assumed that meant that we would need to show that it is both injective and surjective, in addition to continuous. I understand intuitively why they are injective and surjective, and this is what I have so far.

Define $f:(X_1\times\cdot\cdot\cdot\times X_{n−1})\times X_n
\rightarrow X_1\times\cdot\cdot\cdot\times X_n$ by the map $(x_1\times\cdot\cdot\cdot\times x_{n-1})\times x_n\mapsto x_1\times\cdot\cdot\cdot\times x_n$. We must show that $f,f^{-1}$ are continuous and bijective.

Let $x_1\times\cdot\cdot\cdot\times x_n\in X_1\times\cdot\cdot\cdot\times X_n$. Consider that there is some $(x_1\times\cdot\cdot\cdot\times x_{n−1})\times x_n\in(X_1\times\cdot\cdot\cdot\times X_{n−1})\times X_n$ such that $f((x_1\times\cdot\cdot\cdot\times _{n−1})\times x_n)=x_1\times\cdot\cdot\cdot\times x_n$ and thus our function is surjective. Similarly $f^{-1}$ is surjective also.

Now suppose that $x_1\times\cdot\cdot\cdot\times x_n=y_1\times\cdot\cdot\cdot\times y_n$. This implies that $x_i=y_i$ for all $i$. Then the preimage of $x_i$ must be the same as the preimage of $y_i$. This means that $(x_1\times\cdot\cdot\cdot\times x_{n−1})\times x_n=(y_1\times\cdot\cdot\cdot\times y_{n−1})\times y_n$ and thus $f$ is injective. Similarly $f^{-1}$ is injective.

Obviously I have not yet shown that it is continuous. But, I do not think that what I have is rigorous, and so I was wondering what exactly I am missing in making this a more convincing argument before moving on.

Comment: Seems good to me. Why exactly do you "not think what you have is rigorous?"

Comment: Instead of checking injectivity and surjectivity, you can in this case easily state the inverse function, and check (it‘s more or less by definition) that it is indeed an inverse function. Regarding the continuity (of **both** functions), it seems to me that you have to go down to the explicit topologies on both product constructions and check it by hand. Using a category theoretic argument would greatly simplify this, but this does not seem appropriate to your question..

Comment: @NoahCaplinger I have had multiple graders and teachers say that I am not rigorous enough in my proofs for injectivity. I thought I would check with the community first before I assumed that it was ok.

Comment: @NewbieMather “rigor” is a subjective thing. In a class, you do whatever he teachers/graders say. In the “real (math) world,” rigor just means making a convincing argument.